# LWC file upload issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, files, upload

I use the sample below to do the upload file in LWC:

html:

```
<template>
  <lightning-file-upload
        label="Attach receipt"
        name="fileUploader"
        accept={acceptedFormats}
        record-id={myRecordId}
        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
        multiple>
  </lightning-file-upload>
</template>
```

js：

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponentName extends LightningElement {
@api
myRecordId;

get acceptedFormats() {
    return ['.pdf', '.png'];
 }

handleUploadFinished(event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    alert("No. of files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
 }
}
```

But when I push to org., it cannot click the upload file button.
May I know what causing this issue?

Comment: sorry html part:
'''
<template>
    <lightning-file-upload
            label="Attach receipt"
            name="fileUploader"
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            record-id={myRecordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            multiple>
    </lightning-file-upload>
</template>
'''

Comment: where are you loading this component?

Comment: I loading this component in an app in App luncher.

Comment: Can you please share your js-meta.xml for the component? Please make sure that the component is added to a detail record page and not to an application or home page as it requires the record Id for the file upload template to work.

Comment: In your example code I would change myRecordId to recordId, in both the html and js.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: [Usage Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation)

> This component is not supported in Lightning Out or standalone apps,
>   and displays as a disabled input. Additionally, if the Don't allow
>   HTML uploads as attachments or document records security setting is
>   enabled for your organization, the file uploader cannot be used to
>   upload files with the following file extensions: .htm, .html, .htt,
>   .htx, .mhtm, .mhtml, .shtm, .shtml, .acgi, .svg. For more information,
>   see Upload and Share Files in Salesforce Help.

You need to check below:

1. Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records security setting
2. Lightning Out or standalone apps - is not supported

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I am the newer for salesforce lwc for the item 2 Lightning Out or standalone apps - is not supported.
May I know what is for Lightning out? I just add the component to an application in App Luncher, is that Lightning out or standalong app

Comment: to an application means? Are you using `aura:application` in it?

Comment: Add an new lightning App in App manager and not use the aura:application.
Just add the lwc to new lightning app.